# It is possible in AngularJS to detect if template is already loaded in cache?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching, routes

I'm using $routeProvider to load differents types of templates and then, for optimisations purposes a jquery ajax request to get the JSON datas which will be parsed in the template.

When the page loading, i would like an overlay to hide the empty template or the previous template with new datas depending if the cache is already set or not.

So now, i would like to know if there a way to get the differents cached templates from $routeProvider to know if i set the overlay in the datas ajax call or in the template ajax call by using:

```
$scope.on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(scope, next, current){
 if($cacheFactory.get('myurl')
    /* dont use overlay here */
 else
    /* use overlay*/ });
```

But the problem is that actually, i dont find any way to let $cacheFactory working with $routeProvider.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following approach when wishing to hide a template whilst I make a trip to the server.

**DOM** (Add to top off template)

`<div ng-show="showLoading" class="loading"><h4>Loading&#8230;</h4></div>`

**CSS** (Minified)

```
.loading,.loading:before{position:fixed;top:0;left:0}.loading:before,.loading:not(:required):after{content:'';display:block}.loading{z-index:999;height:2em;width:2em;overflow:show;margin:auto;bottom:0;right:0}.loading:before{width:100%;height:100%;background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.3)}.loading:not(:required){font:0/0 a;color:transparent;text-shadow:none;background-color:transparent;border:0}.loading:not(:required):after{font-size:10px;width:1em;height:1em;margin-top:-.5em;-webkit-animation:spinner 1.5s infinite linear;-moz-animation:spinner 1.5s infinite linear;-ms-animation:spinner 1.5s infinite linear;-o-animation:spinner 1.5s infinite linear;animation:spinner 1.5s infinite linear;border-radius:.5em;-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,.75) 1.5em 0 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) 0 1.5em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) -1.5em 0 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.5) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0;box-shadow:rgba(0,0,0,.75) 1.5em 0 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) 1.1em 1.1em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) 0 1.5em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) -1.1em 1.1em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) -1.5em 0 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) -1.1em -1.1em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) 0 -1.5em 0 0,rgba(0,0,0,.75) 1.1em -1.1em 0 0}@-webkit-keyframes spinner{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);-moz-transform:rotate(0);-ms-transform:rotate(0);-o-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);-o-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@-moz-keyframes spinner{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);-moz-transform:rotate(0);-ms-transform:rotate(0);-o-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);-o-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@-o-keyframes spinner{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);-moz-transform:rotate(0);-ms-transform:rotate(0);-o-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);-o-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}@keyframes spinner{0%{-webkit-transform:rotate(0);-moz-transform:rotate(0);-ms-transform:rotate(0);-o-transform:rotate(0);transform:rotate(0)}100%{-webkit-transform:rotate(360deg);-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);-ms-transform:rotate(360deg);-o-transform:rotate(360deg);transform:rotate(360deg)}}
```

**Scope**

```
$scope.showLoading = false;
$scope.getData = function(){
   $scope.showLoading = true;
   //Make server trip
   //Once data is returned, set showLoading back to false
   $scope.showLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: This seems good but this solution does not resolve my problem.

Comment: This seems good but this solution does not resolve my problem, in fact, i would like to know if this is possible to check the cache from $routePovider because i have 2 ajax calls which are asynchronous, and the only way to know which of them is the longest is to know if the cache exist, load the overlay on the JSON ajax call, if not, load it on the template ajax call which is sent by $routeProvider.